# String split with RegExp returns empty strings at either end

Tags: javascript, regex

```
// pattern -- <some name with an optional 1/2/3 at end separated by a _>
var re = new RegExp("^\(.*\)_\([1-3]\)$")
"".split(re) 
// returns [""] --- OK
"abc_d_4".split(re) 
// returns ["abc_d_4"] --- OK
"abc_d_3".split(re)
// returns ["", "abc_d", "3", ""] --- WHOA! hoped-for was ["abc_d", "3"]
// similarly, "_3".split(re), "abc_d_3_4_3".split(re)
```

why the extra empty strings at either end in the last case, and how to avoid that? I would definitely appreciate an explanation.

I can see similar questions have been asked before on SO but not this case (or pl point me there)

Comment: @sln if you write that up, I can accept that as most concise answer (apologies OceansOnPluto :-(

Comment: Moved comment to answer.

Comment: Not sure why you escape `(` and `)`. Although the string ends up being the same as `"^(.*)_([1-3])$"`, it's better if you don't escape them at all `"^(.*)_([1-3])$"`. Anyway, it's better to use RegExp literal instead of calling RegExp constructor when you have a fixed pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moved from comment (per request).

Try to split on `/_(?=[1-3]$)/`

Answer (score 1):

Use `.match` instead.

```
"abc_d_3".match(re)
```

That should return this:

```
["abc_d_3", "abc_d", "3"]
```

Comment: I also liked the comment by @sln, and am actually going to use that. It is more concise and the code describes exactly what I am trying to do.